# Flash IDE Version Control - TFS 2008 Integration?

Tags: flash, tfs, integration

Does anybody who work with Flash IDE use any kind of document versioning tool?

Is it possible to integrate with Team Foundation Server 2008? Team Explorer plugin?

Regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

you have eclipse local history

or you can install eclipse SVN plugin

FlashBuilder is eclipse plugin too.

Comment: Any alternative with Visual Studio? Can I use Teamprise to connect with TFS usaind this Eclipse plugin?

Comment: i think yes, why not, Flash IDE based on eclipse, so - yes.